# mysql int field growing bigger than 11 digits

Tags: mysql, database, integer

I have a mysql database, and I am using it as a temprorarily store captcha values. It has a auto incremented id key, with `int(11)` field. What happens if this value gets bigger than 11 digits?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A typical **INT** uses 4 bytes, so it can store the numbers:
Signed: `-2147483648 to 2147483647`
Unsigned: `0 to 4294967295`

A **BIGINT** uses 8 bytes, so it can store the numbers:
Signed: `-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775808`
Unsigned: `0 to 18446744073709551615`

Answer (score 5):

This number (`11`) has absolutely nothing to do with column range - `[SIGNED] INTEGER` defines a range (`-2147483648 - 2147483647`).

Number within parentheses is being used only when combined with `ZEROFILL`. Then it defines the "length" of displayed number, ie. value `275552` will be returned as *string* `00000275552`.

Answer (score 0):

`int(11)` will accept only first 11 digits. rest of them will be discarded.
You can modify your table and change your id datatype from int to `bigint`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you won't get 11 digits. When you reach the maximum value, all values exceeding it will be treated as if they were the maximum value. In the case of auto_increment fields, it will cause all future inserts to fail until you change the column type to a `BIGINT`:

`ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 1`

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the maximum value, all values exceeding it will be treated as if they were the maximum value. In the case of auto_increment fields, it will cause all future inserts to fail until you change the column type to a BIGINT: